# Migrate attributes from a table to another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, migrate

I have two tables :

```
TEST1 : 
attribut1, attribut2, attribut3 

TEST2 : 
attribut4
```

**attribut4 pattern is like "xxxxx yyyyy zzzzz"**

My question is, is it possible to put in TEST1 attribut1 all the "xxxxx", in the attribut2 all the "yyyyy" and in the attribut3 "zzzzz" of the table TEST2?

I tried something like :

```
insert into TEST1(attribut1) SELECT SUBSTRING(attribut4,1,5)::integer FROM TEST2;
```

but it said :

> ERROR:  null value in column "attribut2" violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (xxxxx, null, null).

*(attribut1,attribut2) are PRIMARY KEY.*

Thanks for your answers and for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split_part()`:

```
insert into TEST1 (attribut1, attribut2, attribut3)
    SELECT split_part(attribut4, ' ', 1)::int,
           split_part(attribut4, ' ', 2)::int,
           split_part(attribut4, ' ', 3)::int
    FROM TEST2;
```